# ResultSet.TYPE.FORWARD.ONLY issue

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public static void create() {
    try {
        Connection connection=connect();
        ResultSet resultSet = connection.getMetaData().getCatalogs();

        //iterate each catalog in the ResultSet
        while (resultSet.next()) {

          // Get the database name, which is at position 1
          String databaseName = resultSet.getString(1);

          if(databaseName.equals("library")) {

              //System.out.print("yes");
              Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

              //Drop database if it pre-exists to reset the complete database

              String sql = "DROP DATABASE library";

              stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

          }

        }

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE LIBRARY"; //Create Database

        stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 

        //Some more create table statements//
           

        resultSet.close();

    }

    catch (Exception ex) {

      ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Can anyone Fix this java mysql code??..It shows error of

> ResultSet.TYPE.FORWARD.ONLY

Make this code scrollable please for my project.I have been trying a lot and tried different ways but could not solve this error

Comment: You shouldn't nest calls while doing a resultset loop. Create new connection and perform what you need instead.